# How to prevent specialization of std::vector<bool>

Tags: c++, templates, vector, boolean, specialization

I have a templated class that has a data member of type `std::vector<T>`, where T is also a parameter of my templated class.

In my template class I have quite some logic that does this:

```
T &value = m_vector[index];
```

This doesn't seem to compile when T is a boolean, because the [] operator of std::vector does not return a bool-reference, but a different type.

Some alternatives (although I don't like any of them):

- tell my users that they must not use bool as template parameter
- have a specialization of my class for bool (but this requires some code duplication)

Isn't there a way to tell std::vector not to specialize for bool?

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: Could you just replace T& with `typename std::vector<T>::reference_type`?

Comment: Can you maybe specialize just *parts* of your code for `std::vector<bool>`, too? Kind of an adapter template, that is the same for everything except bool. But for all I know, `std::vector<bool>` is quite an oddball anyway, and breaks a lot of stuff.

Comment: `boost::container::vector` doesn't have the bool specialization. That could be used instead of the std one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You simply cannot have templated code behave regularly for `T` equal to `bool` if your data is represented by `std::vector<bool>` because this is not a container. As pointed out by @Mark Ransom,  you could use `std::vector<char>` instead, e.g. through a trait like this

```
template<typename T> struct vector_trait { typedef std::vector<T> type; };
template<> struct vector_trait<bool> { typedef std::vector<char> type; };
```

and then use `typename vector_trait<T>::type` wherever you currently use `std::vector<T>`. The disadvantage here is that you need to use casts to convert from `char` to `bool`.

An alternative as suggested in your own answer is to write a wrapper with implicit conversion and constructor

```
template<typename T>
class wrapper
{
public:
        wrapper() : value_(T()) {}
        /* explicit */ wrapper(T const& t): value_(t) {}
        /* explicit */ operator T() { return value_; }
private:
        T value_;
};
```

and use `std::vector< wrapper<bool> >` everywhere without ever having to cast. However, there are also disadvantages to this because standard conversion sequences containing real `bool` parameters behave differently than the user-defined conversions with `wrapper<bool>` (the compiler can at most use 1 user-defined conversion, and as many standard conversions as necessary). This means that template code with function overloading can subtly break. You could uncomment the `explicit` keywords in the code above but that introduces the verbosity again.

Comment: A `std::vector<bool>` is not even a _standard container_

Comment: @KonradRudolph yeah, you don't want to override `bool`, but only `vector<bool>`. If only the committee had added a `bitvector` and let `vector<bool>` be a regular vector...

Comment: @Patrick you're welcom, but did you just missclick and remove the acceptance? is there something that needs to be added to this answer?

Comment: I removed the acceptance because I invented an even more elegant solution (based on your input and the input of the other answers).  Please look at my answer and tell me what you think of it.

Comment: @Patrick Did you try my answer in your code and look for how many casts it takes to get it to compile correctly?

Comment: @rhalbersma: In my case, it would require 2 casts, which is reasonable, although I don't like the reinterpret_cast from char& to bool&.  I decide to go for the wrapper implementation, but with an explicit constructor and no conversion operator to prevent unwanted conversions.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Patrick note that in C++11 you can make both the constructor and the conversion operator explicit.

Comment: @rhalbersma, I added the explicit initialization of value_ to the default constructor to make sure it's always correctly initialized.

Answer (score 4):

Use `std::vector<char>` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Would the following work for you?

```
template <typename T>
struct anything_but_bool {
    typedef T type;
};

template <>
struct anything_but_bool<bool> {
    typedef char type;
};

template <typename T>
class your_class {
    std::vector<typename anything_but_bool<T>::type> member;
};
```

Less flippantly, the name `anything_but_bool` should probably be `prevent_bool` or similar.

Comment: Your answer gave me some inspiration.  Can you take a look at my answer and tell me what you think of it?

Answer (score 2):

```
std::basic_string<bool> flags(flagCount, false);
```

Semantically, using `string` is weird, but it works basically like `std::vector`, behaves as expected with pointers/references, and it conveniently converts  to `std::span<bool>` when passing to functions that take span, no need for wrapper classes or reinterpret_cast's (e.g. using `std::vector<uint8_t>` makes these cases awkward because of the casts). Until/unless C++ adds a `std::bit_vector` and deprecates the specialization, we don't have many good options.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom proxy class to hold the bools.

```
class Bool
{
  public:
    Bool() = default;
    Bool(bool in) : value(in) {}

    Bool& operator=(bool in) {value = in;}
    operator bool() const& {return value;}

  private:
    bool value;
};
```

This might require a bit of tweaking for your purposes, but it's usually what I do in these cases.

Comment: Your answer gave me some inspiration.  Can you take a look at my answer and tell me what you think of it?

Answer (score 1):

I found an even more elegant solution, based on all of your input.

First I define a simple class that holds one member.  Let's call this `wrapperClass`:

```
template <typename T>
class wrapperClass
   {
   public:
      wrapperClass() {}
      wrapperClass(const T&value) : m_value(value) {}
      T m_value;
   };
```

Now I can define my std::vector in my templated class like this:

```
std::vector<wrapperClass<T>> m_internalVector;
```

Since `sizeof(WrapperClass<bool>)` is also 1, I expect that `sizeof(WrapperClass<T>)` will always be equal to `sizeof(T)`.  Since the data type is now not a bool anymore, the specialization is not performed.

In places where I now get an element from the vector, I simply replace

```
m_internalVector[index]
```

by

```
m_internalVector[index].m_value
```

But this seems much more elegant than using traits to replace bool by char, and then using casts to convert between char and bool (and probably reinterpret casts to convert char& to bool&).

What do you think?

Comment: Wouldn't it be even shorter to write `template<typename T> struct wrapper { T value_; };` without the constructors?

Comment: BTW, you only need `static_cast`, not `reinterpret_cast` for my answer.

Comment: Then there is no automatic casting from T to wrapperClass<T>, and no default constructor, which leaves the value in the struct undefined.  In my case, I need to do a resize of the vector, and so I need the default constructor.

Comment: static_cast fails when casting references.  You cannot statically-cast a char-reference to a bool-reference.

Comment: If at all, I would *only* wrap `bool` and not the other types (using traits) and then provide **implicit** conversions so that you don’t have to write `foo[index].m_value` but can use `foo[index]` as if it were a proper `bool`.

Comment: @Patrick +1 for the idea, but as @KonradRudolph suggests, add an implicit conversion operator as well. And see my updated answer for the downside of implicit conversions (could break function overloading if you use `wrapper<bool>` instead of `bool`).