# can we create a normal vector<bool> using custom allocator?

Tags: c++, vector, boolean

I recently had to write a bunch of nasty `std::enable_if` specializations to correctly deal with `vector<bool>` for what would have otherwise been a nice and clean design. There is [some talk](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-proposals/FqtPdNDTPmQ) to remove the current `vector<bool>` that should have never been, but in the meantime I would like to have a normal `vector<bool>` that is an actual *standard container* and that internally uses a single array of booleans (`std::deque` is thus not an option, as its storage is not guaranteed to be continuous).

While one could wrap the boolean as for instance suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14387929/3103767), I was wondering whether one could also fix `vector<bool>` by providing a custom allocator? If so, how would one implement this? And why or why not would this solution be preferred over wrapping the boolean value?

Comment: Have you looked at boost::container::vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's impossible to change behaviour of `vector<bool>` with custom allocator. Allocators are designed to handle all the requests for allocation and deallocation of memory for a container. They also can create or destroy objects at specified address but they cannot affect on objects layout inside container. Beside other things `vector<bool>` does not necessarily store its data in a contiguous memory buffer. So options you have are to use another container or another element type for a vector (`char` for example)

Answer (score 0):

try using boost::container::vector that worked for me